# Replacing separate parts of an URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make a bookmarklet that will take part of an URL and redirect to the new URL, but I need to change two parts of the URL that are separate.

The base URL could be:

> **78.media.tumblr.com**/fc87fac5ea0d88e1e22a214d25a169ee/tumblr_p3fjmdiF7f1r9qk1io1**_1280**.png

I need it to end like this:

> **s3.amazonaws.com/data.tumblr.com**/fc87fac5ea0d88e1e22a214d25a169ee/tumblr_p3fjmdiF7f1r9qk1io1**_raw**.png

So I need to replace *"78.media.tumblr.com"* and *"1280"*

I've tried coming up with something using `window.location.assign` and `location.href.replace` but I'm pretty new and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I'd suggest posting the code for your attempt to solve the problem

Comment: Use str_replace(), google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and `window.location.href`. This is assuming you are only looking at tumbler though. If you're not, there would be another step in the regex.

```
// first get the url
var url = window.location.href;

// Use regex to keep only the parts we want and replace the others
var newUrl = url.replace(/.*(\.tumblr.*\_).*(\..*)/, 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/data$1raw$2')

// go to the new page
window.location.href = newUrl;
```

Comment: Hmm, this is almost perfect except it redirects to the wrong page; instead of replacing the entire URL, it's replacing half the old URL with newURL so I got something like https://78.media.tumblr.com/fc87fac5ea0d88e1e22a214d25a169ee/s3.amazonaws.com/data.tumblr.com/fc87fac5ea0d88e1e22a214d25a169ee/tumblr_p3fjmdiF7f1r9qk1io1_raw.png

Comment: Btw, That comic is awesome.

Comment: Yup! that did it, thank you so much :> _(and yes, love this comic lol)_

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can just replace the parts of the string using String.prototype.replace. Depending on how flexible you need the matching to be you can adjust the regexes to be more or less 'matchy'.

```js
const startUrl = '78.media.tumblr.com/fc87fac5ea0d88e1e22a214d25a169ee/tumblr_p3fjmdiF7f1r9qk1io1_1280.png'

const endUrl = 's3.amazonaws.com/data.tumblr.com/fc87fac5ea0d88e1e22a214d25a169ee/tumblr_p3fjmdiF7f1r9qk1io1_raw.png'

const tumblerRegex = /.*\.tumblr\.com/
const numberRegex = /_\d{4}/

function transform (start) {
  return start.replace(tumblerRegex, 's3.amazonaws.com/data.tumblr.com').replace(numberRegex, '_raw')
  }
  
  console.log(transform(startUrl) == endUrl)
```